# Console.log repeating output in each getJSON loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitch

Could someone tell me why my console.log is returning the same output for every loop and how to fix it? The console.log should be returning each element of the 'channels' array, but it keeps outputting the last element 'noobs2ninjas'.

It is a similar function to the FCC Twitch app [here](https://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/Myvqmo/). The difference is that I swapped the .$getJSON order. Their app is getting the 'stream' first while I'm getting the 'channel' first. I've been comparing my code and theirs and could not understand why the inner .$getJSON will be repeating the same array element over and over again but the outter .$getJSON is looping through each element correctly.

```
function loadChannel() {
    var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
    var display_name = null;
    var logo = null;
    var url = null;
    var game = null;
    var status = null;
    var online = false;

    function api(type, channel) {
        return `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/${type}/${channel}?callback=?`;
    }

    for (var index in channels) {
        $.getJSON(api('channels', channels[index]), function(data) {
            display_name = data.display_name;
            logo = data.logo;
            url = data.url;
            game = data.game;
            status = data.status;
            $.getJSON(api('streams', channels[index]), function(data) {
                // get online status
                console.log(channels[index]); // <-- outputs same channel 'noobs2ninjas' each loop
                console.log(data); // <-- outputs same object each loop
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `var` in Javascript is function scoped, not block scoped; your `var index` declaration is being hoisted to the the top of loadChannels and is overwritten each loop. This means that your async functions are only accessing the last index, since the loop finishes before the ajax calls do. There *is* a nice solution that you are pretty close to already though.

Using your existing code you could switch out just the for loop and instead utilize `Array.forEach`. You will pass it a function that will create a new scope with the *channel* scoped locally to the loop (and therefore not overwritten on each iteration).

```
function loadChannel() {
    var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
    var display_name = null;
    var logo = null;
    var url = null;
    var game = null;
    var status = null;
    var online = false;

    function api(type, channel) {
        return `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/${type}/${channel}?callback=?`;
    }

    channels.forEach(function (channel) {
        $.getJSON(api('channels', channel), function(data) {
            display_name = data.display_name;
            logo = data.logo;
            url = data.url;
            game = data.game;
            status = data.status;
            $.getJSON(api('streams', channel), function(data) {
                // get online status
                console.log(channel); // <-- should be fixed
                console.log(data); // <-- outputs same object each loop
            });
        });
    });
}
```

It might also be wise to move the declaration of any other variables you plan to use inside the loop (display_name, logo,  etc) into the forEach we just made.

References:

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Thanks for the hoisting and forEach explanation. I didn't want to copy outright their code and my original implementation was using a regular for loop and got the same issue. I assumed the reason FCC's code worked is because they had embedded one async request within another async request, and also forEach was exactly the same as the for loop which you've revealed is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Because `$.getJSON`is asyncronous, and by the time its callback is called, the loop is already over and `index` will hold the latest value of the loop.

You should [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) your function to have `index` as first parameter, as:

```
for (var index in channels) {
  (function(i){
     $.getJSON(api('channels', channels[i]), function(data){
       ...
       // channels[i] is what you want here
       $.getJSON(api('streams', channels[i]), function(data) {
         ...
       });
     });
  }.bind(null, index))()
}
```

---

But in this specific case, why not `channels.forEach(function(channel){ ... }`?

Comment: How is FCC's app able to get around this? I inserted console.log after each getJSON and its not repeating the same element in their code?

Comment: Because they use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Thanks. I thought the reason their code worked is because they embedded one async request within another async request.